# MYSQL error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (1045)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I get the following error when trying to connect to my database after uploading my files to CPanel. It all works fine locally. It doesn't matter if I have a root password or not.

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (1045)

I am using PHPMyAdmin, XAMPP and MariaDB.

My credentials are as follows:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "Password");
define("DB_NAME", "portfolio_db");
```

Config file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Update:

I have now imported the database to CPanel and created a user attached to it. I have also updated the credentials so they correspond to the user. I am however unsure what the server should be and if there are any additional credentials I need to add to make it work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From cpanel , you have to create a DB user and its password and then assign all previleges from cpanel it self. Use the username and password that you have created from Cpanel and that will fix the issue.

Comment: So I just imported the database to cpanel and created a user attached to it, with all privileges. However, it is not working. I get the same error. I have updated the credentials with the new database name, user and password. I am not sure though what the server should be and if there are additional credentials I need to add.